# How can I delete a product from the cart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on an e-commerce and I have a problem with remove products from the cart. I tried to create a function but without success, I honestly don't know what to do to make it work...
The error I see is this:
'TypeError: this.props.data.filter is not a function'

```
//Shopping.js
class Shopping extends Component{ 
        componentDidMount(){
            const products =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'));
            this.setState({products});    
        }   
        render(){
            const products =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products')) || [];        
            return(
                <div>
                 <h3>Shopping Cart</h3>                                         
                   {products.map((product, key) =>
                      <CartProduct key={key} data={product}/> 
                   )} 
                </div>  
            )
        }
    }
    export default Shopping;

    //CartProduct.js   
class CartProduct extends React.Component{
        //this is where the error comes from
        removeProduct(data){
            const prod = this.props.data.filter(i => i.id !== data.id)
            this.setState({prod})
        }
        render(){  
            return(
                <div>
                    <img 
                       src={this.props.data.img}
                    />
                    <h4>{this.props.data.name}</h4>
                    <span>{this.props.data.description}</span>
                    <h4 >${this.props.data.price}</h4>
                    <Button 
                        onClick={this.removeProduct.bind(this)}
                    >Remove</Button>                               
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
    export default withRouter(CartProduct);
```

Comment: The issue seems with your `removeProduct` function. Inside the function `this` doesn't  refer the component. You better use arrow function here like `removeProduct =(data)=>{..`

Comment: The function is bound, what's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a function that will be triggered by `CardProduct` component. Let's say `onRemove`. Implementation of this function will live inside `Shopping` component as your `products` state lives there. The only thing that will take place in your `CardProduct` is invoking of `onRemove` function with `id` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will help:

```
//Shopping.js
class Shopping extends Component{      
  componentDidMount(){
    const products =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'));
    this.setState({products});    
  }

  removeProduct = (pId) =>{
    let products  = this.state.products.filter(product => product.id !== pId);
    this.setState({products});    
  }
  render(){
      const products =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products')) || [];        
      return(
          <div>
            <h3>Shopping Cart</h3>                                         
              {products.map((product, key) =>
                <CartProduct key={key} data={product} removeProduct={this.removeProduct}/> 
              )} 
          </div>  
      )
  }
}
    export default Shopping;

//CartProduct.js   
class CartProduct extends React.Component{
  render(){  
      return(
          <div>
              <img 
                  src={this.props.data.img}
              />
              <h4>{this.props.data.name}</h4>
              <span>{this.props.data.description}</span>
              <h4 >${this.props.data.price}</h4>
              <Button 
                  onClick={this.props.removeProduct(this.props.data.id)}
              >Remove</Button>                               
          </div>
      )
  }
    }
    export default withRouter(CartProduct);
```

As your `products` list is in your parent component `Shopping`, so you need to keep the removal power to the parent component. Simply pass product ID from the child component to parent component and delete product in the parent. 
Let me know if that helps you out.

Comment: Code without explanation is not as useful

Answer (score 0):

You are updating state of child component in your code while you have to update the state in parent component .make a function handleOnRemoval in parent component and pass this function as a prop to the child component and implenet the same logic in that function .when function is called in child component it will trigger the handle event of parent component